# Given $a_1 =1, a_{n+1}=a_n+e^{-a_n}$. Prove that $b_n:=a_n-\ln(n)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Given the sequence $a_1 =1, a_{n+1}=a_n+e^{-a_n}$.
>   Prove that $b_n:=a_n-\ln(n)$ converges.

I have just known $\lim a_n =\infty$.
I have tried to prove $b_{n+1} \leq b_n$ but I didn't make it.
Help me, thank you so much

Comment: There's an answer which you can follow at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674093/sequence-x-n1-x-ne-2018x-n

Comment: What is definition of $b_n$?

Comment: @Arjang $b_n:=a_n-\ln n$

Comment: @RobertZ : "Prove that bn:=an−ln(n) is convergent " or "Prove that bn:=an−ln(n) converges"? havent seen the former in literature.

Comment: @Did In my opinion the question is not a duplicate. OP asks about the convergence of $a_n-\ln(n)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RobertZ Hmmm, the difference is tiny and this uses basically the tools used to solve the other question but ok, I reopened it (and then this might be reclosed for lack of context...).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\big(x_n-\ln(n+1)\big)$ for $x_{n+1}=x_n+e^{-x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58866/lim-limits-n-to-infty-bigx-n-lnn1-big-for-x-n1-x-ne-x-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By following  Professor Vector's answer given in [sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n+e^{-2018x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674093/sequence-x-n1-x-ne-2018x-n) (see Patrick Stevens' hint) we have that $e^{a_n}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=1$ and
$$e^{a_n}-e=\int_{a_1}^{a_n}e^t dt\geq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{a_k}(a_{k+1}-a_k)=n-1$$
and therefore $a_n\geq \ln(n-1+e)$. Then 
$$b_n=a_n-\ln(n)\geq \ln\left(1+\frac{e-1}{n}\right)>0.$$
Moreover (this part is **NOT** contained in the linked answer) $b_{n+1}\leq b_n$ iff
$$e^{-a_n}=a_{n+1}-a_n\leq \ln(n+1)-\ln(n)=\ln(1+1/n)$$
which is implied by (recall that $\ln(1+x)\geq x(1-x)$ for $x>0$),
$$\frac{1}{n-1+e}\leq \frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
that is
$$n^2\leq (n-1)(n-1+e)-1=n^2+(e-2)n+1-e$$
which holds for $n>2$.

Hence we may conclude that $b_n$ is eventually decreasing and positive and it follows that it tends to a non negative limit.